# overriding JNDI names in JBoss EJB3.1

Tags: jboss, ejb, java-ee-6, ejb-3.1, jboss-eap-6

We're using Maven and Artifactory, and therefore our ear files have names like

```
 our-project-ear-0.0.1-20151215.151526-3.ear.
```

So JNDI names for our EJBs have names like

```
java:global/our-project-ear/our-project-ejb/AnEjbJar!com.acme.ourproject.SomeEjb.
```

These names are not just ugly and complex, they also embed temporary suffixes added by Maven/Artifactory.

I thought we could simplify the names via the JBoss-specific `@RemoteHomeBinding` annotation, but I do not find this annotation in EAP 6.3. Is there still a way to do this? If not, how can I control the JNDI name under which my EJBs are published?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out myself. The `@RemoteBinding`, `@LocalBinding`, `@RemoteHomeBinding` and `@LocalHomeBinding` annotations have been phased out in AS7.x. [A version of the JBoss instructions for migrating from AS5/6 to AS7 (not the current one)](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/How+do+I+migrate+my+application+from+AS5+or+AS6+to+AS7) states:

```
>In AS7 there is no possibility for custom JNDI names of EJB beans and it's not planned for 7.1.

>Therefor the annotation @RemoteBindings and @LocalBindings are not available.
```

The recommended approach is to use the default bindings. However, custom JNDI names can also be defined via the `@EJB` annotation, as stated in [this Oracle blog](https://blogs.oracle.com/kensaks/entry/application_specified_portable_jndi_names):

> The developer can select an additional JNDI name that resolves to a particular client view of a session bean by using the @EJB annotation. Starting with Java EE 6, the @EJB name() attribute value can be prefixed with any one of the three portable Java EE namespaces : java:global, java:app, java:module. This has the effect of exporting the dependency into the selected scope.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is :

```
@Ejb(lookup="java:/global/somecustomPath")
```

As this will not affect where in JNDI the bean is bound but rather where to find it in JNDI.

If I'm right this is because JBOSS7 is a JEE6 application server and JEE6 introduced the concept of Portable Global JNDI names in JEE6.